# HTTP call to another component on the same server - does the traffic go out on the network?

Tags: networking, http

A TLS connection terminates at a component on my server. This component then makes an HTTP call to another component on the same server.

Does this connection go out onto the network (out of the server and back in again?) and hence viewable with packet sniffer etc. or does the call happen within the server and not visible on the network?

Comment: Hi Durathor, welcome to Unix & Linux SE! When asking a question, try to include as much relevant information as you can. For example, what OS are you running? What IP address is the request to? (`127.0.0.1` or `192.168.0.35` or `8.8.8.8` can make a _big_ difference) What port is the request to? What is your firewall setup (if any)? Please edit your question to include this information and any other relevant information you can think of :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this question was already answered here:

[Why isn't there a route for localhost in Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/683538/why-isnt-there-a-route-for-localhost-in-ubuntu)

In short, linux have several types of routing tables. The one you see when you type

```
ip ro show
```

is the 'main' table, used for external connections. Before that you have the routing table 'local'. In order to see it, type:

```
ip ro show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src     127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.0.0 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.27 
local 192.168.1.27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.1.27 
broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.27
```

There are your local IPs and if the IP can be found in the local table it isn't supposed to be routed outside the node.

Comment: Thanks - I found this link which is also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860626/does-a-connection-to-localhost-go-out-onto-the-network